# How can I hide source code of angular app from browser

Tags: angular, browser

my question is how to hide the source code of an angular application from browser, because i created a web app  with angular , but the source code is appear on the development tool, and i don't know how to hide it and protect my code.
thank you for your help

Comment: You can't: the browser needs access to the code in order to execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for typical web applications based upon HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

What you can do is take extra measures to uglify your code which makes it difficult but not impossible to recreate it.

For this to happen you have to build your code using the [--prod flag](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#build-with---prod) which also offers other advantages.

Comment: Are there other ways to do this other than --prod ?